# Brass tablet at a museum in Rouen: "A tous les temps, a tous les peuples"

Tags: metric

In the book by Sheppard from 1817
"Letters descriptive of a Tour through some parts of France, Italy, Switzerland, and Germany in 1816, with incidental reflections on some topics connected with Religion"

on page 12

the author mentions a brass tablet about the creation of the metric system.

Is this tablet still there? I could not locate it. Is the tablet itself today in a museum?[image]

Comment: In general, questions where the title asks a question fit better in a Q&A site - they tend to get more answers, perhaps because people understand what you want to know.

Comment: I emailed the museum in Rouen where the authors claimed to have found it. They moved to a bigger building in the 1880s. If I hear back from them I will let you know.